# Possible to make a subdirectory that loops through a single category?

Tags: categories, permalinks, templates

I'm trying to separate the main part of my blog (the informational portion) from more commercial parts.

WHen you load my homepage, I purposely exclude a category because I don't want my normal readers to be bothered with affiliate links and such.

I'd like to add a subdirectory /reviews/ for example, that loops through the reviews category and displays them all on one page, just like how the category template works.

There are 2 reasons I don't want to use the category template:

1) I have my SEO settings to block indexing on my category template
2) The /category/ in the permalinks is ugly to me.

Is it possible to accomplish domain.com/reviews/ where it functions just like the category template? Am I stuck with manually building a page? Or am I stuck with domain.com/category/reviews ?

I have looked into building a "network" with Wordpress MU, but it says I can't do that anymore since my blog is >1 month old. Plus it's kinda technical.

I basically want to add more blogs to my site (to keep everything nicely separated), so I am trying to figure out a workaround by just excluding/including certain categories where I want them.

Am I making sense? Haha thanks to all who take the time out of their day to reply :)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a separate category template for just that one category. If your category's slug is `reviews` you can make a copy of your category template and save it as `category-reviews.php`.

See the [Category Templates page on Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates) for more info about the template hierarchy.

This still leaves you with the `/category/` part in the permalink, which you can either change to something else globally in the permalink settings, or you can maybe create a custom rewrite rule just for that category.

Comment: @John: If it answered your question, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes... custom rewrite rule is the way to go! Check this out [Is there a PHP function that can match anything after the given URL, so my IF statement will work in each instance?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/23195/is-there-a-php-function-that-can-match-anything-after-the-given-url-so-my-if-sta/23621#23621)... You'll get a way to write new URL rewrite rule as per your need.